# pg_restore with -C option does not create the database

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am using pg_dump and pg_restore for backup and restore of postgres database.

Here is some information from documentation that will be relevant for this question
For Pg_restore, -C option is described as follows

> -C
>
> --create
>
> Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also specified, > >  drop and recreate the target database before
>    connecting to it. When this option is used, the database named with -d
>    is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE
>    commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in
>    the archive.

However even when I use this option with pg_restore, I get following error

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "test" failed:
>   FATAL:  >  database "test" does not exist

As per the description the -C option should have  created the missing database. However it does not in my case.

Following are the steps that I did for backup and restore:

1. Use pg_dump to backup database

```
pg_dump -N backup -d test --format custom -v -h xxhostxx -p 5432 -U xxuserxx --lock-wait-timeout 300000 -f test_pg_dump.dmp
```

Note: not using -C option since it is meaningful for the plain-text formats only

2. Deleted the **test** database
3. use pg_resore to restore database

   ```
   pg_restore -C -d test -v -h xxhostxx -p 5432 -U xxuserxx test_pg_dump.dmp**
   ```

I cannot understand what is the issue here! Am I doing anything wrong ?
Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Exactly like @Eelke said - you've got in file wrote 'create database' so this database does not exist when you're running script... That's what for there is always 'postgres' database. Try this:

```
pg_restore -C -d postgres -v -h xxhostxx -p 5432 -U xxuserxx test_pg_dump.dmp**
```

And this should:

1. connect to postgres database
2. Create test database
3. Disconnect from postgres and connect to test
4. Upload data into database

Of course check who is owner of postgres database - in most cases you have to run this as user 'postgres'.

Answer (score 17):

It never worked for me so this command creates the database

```
createdb -h HOST -U USER -W DB_NAME
```

then execute the pg restore

```
pg_restore -d DB_NAME -v -h HOST -p PORT -U USER DUMP_FILE.dump**
```

End of story

Comment: it is part of the pg installation. Depends on you OS and PG version. I was using ubuntu 18.04 and PG9

Answer (score 16):

The following quote doesn't mean what you might think it means. I also had to read it thrice before realizing what they were saying.

> When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to
>   issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data
>   is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

It means that pg_restore will initially connect to the database specified with -d. It will NOT create that database. It creates a database with the name from the archive you are restoring and restores the data into that database.

Comment: does this mean you cannot restore a database if it does not exist? 
To restore you need to issue a command to create an empty database first and then restore?

Comment: @Swapnil17: you always have an empty database: `template1`

Comment: Wow, I've been using these tools far too long to learn this only now. What a weird way of working!

Answer (score 2):

From `man pg_restore` `EXAMPLES` section

```
Assume we have dumped a database called mydb into a custom-format dump file:

   $ pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump

To drop the database and recreate it from the dump:

   $ dropdb mydb
   $ pg_restore -C -d postgres db.dump

The database named in the -d switch can be any database existing in the cluster; pg_restore only uses it to issue the CREATE DATABASE command for mydb.
With -C, data is always restored into the database name that appears in the dump file.

To reload the dump into a new database called newdb:

   $ createdb -T template0 newdb
   $ pg_restore -d newdb db.dump

Notice we don't use -C, and instead connect directly to the database to be restored into. Also note that we clone the new database from template0 not
template1, to ensure it is initially empty.
```

**Thus in your case:**

```
$ createdb -h xxhostxx -p 5432 -U xxuserxx -T template0 test
$ pg_restore -h xxhostxx -p 5432 -U xxuserxx -d test db.dump
```

Comment: in the same section there is a mention to `pg_restore -l db.dump > db.lis` that will show you the name of the orginal db backuped